# Can't get more than 2 ethernet-connected devices online on home network. What's wrong with my setup?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, switch

I'm a network noob and I don't understand what I've done wrong with our home setup. Probably this is a symptom of a rudimentary misunderstanding of how these devices should be working in tandem.

#### Context/Circumstance

Until today, I had one PC, and a set of Access Points (but only one AP is wired) wired into a 16-Port-Switch into our modem, and both devices enjoyed internet. Today, I tried to add a new switch and a PC and am struggling.

From our ISP, we have a COAX coming into the house which meets a [TC4400 modem](https://www.amazon.ca/Technicolor-TC4400VDN-Ultra-Broadband-Cable-Modem/dp/B082F3MG1D) from our ISP. This modem (which is just a modem, no bridge mode) has 1 coax port which is occupied by our incoming COAX, and 2 ethernet ports on it, one of which is connected to a [NETGEAR 16-Port Gigabit Switch](https://www.netgear.com/ca-en/business/wired/switches/unmanaged/jgs516/) which I got from my old office a few years ago.

In this NETGEAR 16-Port Gigabit Switch, I run 2 CAT6 cables away,

1. to a mesh-router AP called a [TP-LINK Deco M5](https://www.tp-link.com/ca/home-networking/deco/deco-m5/), which also provides WiFi to two other AP's (which I hope to wire also someday).
2. to an office on the second floor, where it meets a cheap $16 [TP-Link 5-Port Gigabit Switch](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/5-port-switch/tl-sg1005d/), to then service two PC's in the office which both desire ethernet.

[Image of network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AITPx.png)

#### Problem Statement

In the above diagram, only 2 connected devices are able to have internet at a time. Either the Mesh Router (AP1) is allowed to serve WiFi, and one of the PC's is able to have internet, OR the Router is not able to have internet and the two PC's are able to have internet. The way to get this to switch is to basically turn everything off, and only have the 2 'desired' systems connected to the modem somehow, which then ensures the 3rd one cannot once everything's booted up.

### TL;DR Only 2/3 colours are allowed online at once

#### Things I have tried

-Trying lots of ports on either switches
-Turning everything off and on multiple times
-Connecting the Deco AP1 router to the TC4400 modem's other ethernet port, so that it is 'separate' from the 16-Port switch

#### Things I have not yet tried but will be trying shortly

-Swapping the TP-Link 5-Port cheapie switch with the beefy 16-Port Switch
-Trying to put my beefy 16-Port Switch 'behind' the Deco AP1 Router
-Calling my ISP to ask if there's some kind of issue with the modem and I'm demanding too much of it with 2 wired ethernet devices (I pay for their top package!)

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOCSIS (cable modem) standard requires modem-only modems to only talk to a single Ethernet device. So the first unicast MAC address it sees after booting is the only one it will talk to until it is rebooted.

You need to put a single NAT gateway router behind your modem, and then build the rest of your network behind that router. You can't use a switch because a switch doesn't hide the MAC addresses of all the other devices attached to it, so it becomes unpredictable which device your DOCSIS modem will latch onto after each reboot.

The only reason your TC4400 has two gigabit Ethernet ports is because its DOCSIS interface supports speeds in excess of gigabit Ethernet's max speed (after subtracting overhead) of 943Mbps. So to get its full DOCSIS speeds across to Ethernet, you'd need two gigabit Ethernet ports configured for link aggregation (i.e. "bonded" together). Using two 1Gbps ports this way is cheaper and more broadly compatible than a single 2.5Gbps, 5Gbps, or 10Gbps Ethernet port.

Comment: Very interesting. Ok, to solve the immediate problem, I need a single NAT gateway router. Before I rush out and buy something beyond my needs, do you have any reccomendation between [this TP-Link one](https://www.amazon.ca/TP-Link-Multi-WAN-Wired-Router-ER605/dp/B08QTXNWZ1/ref=sr_1_3?crid=11O3CGM70BODL&keywords=gigabit+router&qid=1656990009&s=electronics&sprefix=gigabit+router%2Celectronics%2C77&sr=1-3) and this [Ubiquiti one](https://tinyurl.com/5x8vfc2x)?

Comment: Also, I believe your explanation wholeheartedly, but one bit is slightly askew for me, you're saying the modem latches onto the first ONE MAC address it sees, but per my experience and diagram, the modem agrees to talk to two MAC's, e.g. PC1+PC2/PC1+APs/PC2+APs., am I in the twilight zone?

Comment: @driftandwander Hmm, I must have skimmed your question too fast. This would be the first time I've ever heard of a DOCSIS modem-only modem that will talk to two MAC addresses, but it sure sounds like that's what's going on here. Also, you don't necessarily have to go out and buy a separate NAT gateway box; your main Deco can probably serve that purpose.